# Laravel 5.4 - Bind AuthServiceProvider to route group?

Tags: php, authentication, authorization, roles, laravel-5.4

My routes are split up into 2 groups: the `web`(default) group and the `admin`(custom) group. The `admin` group uses the `auth` middleware. Everything else uses the `web` middleware.

I'm having an issue where my AuthServiceProvider is querying my Permissions model in both groups... but I only want to query my Permissions model when a user requests access to a route within my `admin` group. Here is my AuthServiceProvider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\Permission;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
 /**
 * The policy mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $policies = [
    'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy'
];

/**
 * Register any authentication / authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Gate::before( function($user){
        if($user->isAdmin()){
            return true;
        }
    });

    foreach ($this->getPermissions() as $permission) {
        Gate::define($permission->name, function ($user) use ($permission) {
            return $user->hasRole($permission->roles);
        });
    }
}

protected function getPermissions()
{
    return Permission::with('roles')->get();
}
```

So in every request within my `web` middleware, my app is querying permissions for a user when it doesnt need to. There is no *need* for any permissions to get queried within my web middleware. So how do I tell my AuthServiceProvider to check permissions for only routes within my `Auth` group (or middleware)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[answer is here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-54-bind-authserviceprovider-to-route-group)

I just switched from using a service provider to using my own custom middleware